# Github Pages redirect only works locally, but not on the remote Github server (got 404)

Tags: url, redirect, jekyll, github-pages

When I click on the tags on the right of my Github pages, it always give me a 404 page. However, when I preview it locally, the redirect seem to work just fine:

[image]

I wonder if it has something to do with my [`_config.yml`](https://github.com/ChangyuYan/changyuyan.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml). I have tried different url and baseurl strings, but still couldn't resolve it.

(Note: This theme was adopted from [Chirpy](https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy))

Thanks!

---

Part of my `config.yml`:

```yaml
title: Changyu Yan

url: 'https://changyuyan.github.io'

# Only if your site type is GitHub Project sites and doesn't have a custom domain,
# change below value to '/projectname'.
baseurl: ''
timezone: America/Los_Angeles

google_analytics:
  id: ''
  pv:
    # The Google Analytics pageviews switch.
    # DO NOT enable it unless you know how to deploy the Google Analytics superProxy.
    enabled: false
    # the next options only valid when `google_analytics.pv` is enabled.
    proxy_url: ''
    proxy_endpoint: ''
    cache: false  # pv data local cache, good for the users from GFW area.

# boolean type, the global switch for ToC in posts.
toc: true

paginate: 10

kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:   # Rouge Options › https://github.com/jneen/rouge#full-options
    css_class: highlight
    # default_lang: console
    span:
      line_numbers: false
    block:
      line_numbers: true
      start_line: 1

# DO NOT change this unless you're a Pro user on Jekyll and Web development,
# or you think you're smart enough to change other relevant URLs within this template.
permalink: /posts/:title/

collections:
  tabs:
    output: true
    sort_by: order


defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ''          # An empty string here means all files in the project
      type: posts
    values:
      layout: post
      comments: true    # Enable comments in posts.
      toc: true         # Display TOC column in posts.
      breadcrumb:
        -
          label: Posts
          url: /
  -
    scope:
      path: _drafts
    values:
      comments: false
  -
    scope:
      path: index.html
    values:
      breadcrumb:
        -
          label: Posts
  -
    scope:
      path: tags
    values:
      breadcrumb:
        -
          label: Home
          url: /
        -
          label: Tags
          url: /tabs/tags/
  -
    scope:
      path: categories
    values:
      breadcrumb:
        -
          label: Home
          url: /
        -
          label: Categories
          url: /tabs/categories/
  -
    scope:
      path: ''
      type: tabs             # see `site.collections`
    values:
      layout: page
      dynamic_title: true    # Hide title in mobile screens.
      breadcrumb:
        -
          label: Home
          url: /

sass:
  sass_dir: /assets/css
  style: compressed

compress_html:
  clippings: all
  comments: all
  endings: all
  profile: false
  blanklines: false
  ignore:
    envs: []

exclude:
  - vendor
  - Gemfile.lock
  - Gemfile
  - tools
  - docs
  - README.md
  - LICENSE

jekyll-archives:
  enabled: [categories, tags]
  layouts:
    category: category
    tag: tag
  permalinks:
    tag: /tags/:name/
    category: /categories/:name/
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippets for (1) creating the URL that's not working properly and (2) the part of your `_config.yaml` that sets the base URL?

Comment: Just updated the description with the code :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The archives are working locally and not on GitHub Pages because the jekyll-archives gem is [not supported in GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/). You can see in the notes for Chirpy, under [Deploy on GitHub Pages](https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy#deploy-on-github-pages), an option for using [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions). This should allow you to run unsupported plugins (there is a good [tutorial by Aneejian](https://aneejian.com/automated-jekyll-archives-github-pages/)).

Another option is to manually build all your tag pages. You would need to create a `tag` directory and inside that, create all the tag files (software-engineering.html). Inside those you'd run a `for` loop for that tag. You have a couple of options:

```
{% for post in site.tags.software-engineering %}
```

or

```
{% for post in site.posts | where: 'tag', 'software-engineering' %}
```

There are others that may better suit your use-case.

Per the `baseurl` discussion, you do not need that if you do not use a project directory. If you wanted https://changyuyan.github.io/blog/tags/software-engineering/, you'd need to add `baseurl: '/blog` ...but it doesn't look like you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Near the top of your `_config.yml`, set `baseurl` to the name of the project repo according to the instructions:

```yaml
# Only if your site type is GitHub Project sites and doesn't have a custom domain,
# change below value to '/projectname'.
baseurl: '/changyuyan.github.io'
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that. Still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @Erin what are the values of the URLs that give a 404?

Comment: Just all the links if I click on the tags on the right. For example, this one: https://changyuyan.github.io/changyuyan.github.io/tags/software-engineering/